Why doesn't a complex key lookup in map work?
I have a map, where the key that is a combination of a string and a number - I assume it is an object then.
Why does the following code return false on the has() method, when I use the exact same keys (const key = {app:"App", code:5};)?


let errorItemPages = new Map();

function addItem() {
    const key = {app:"App", code:5};
    errorItemPages.set(key, "five");
}

function lookup() {
    const key = {app:"App", code:5};
    console.log(errorItemPages.has(key));
}

addItem();
lookup();




"Doesn't work" isn't particularly helpful to us. What is your expectation of the code and what is it actually doing instead? What steps have you taken to debug it?

Because the equality is determined by identity, and those are not the "exact same" object.
